# Embedding picture to outlook email body

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
string imageSrc = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\menonsu\\Desktop\\screenScrapper\\Bitmap1.bmp";
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><img src = \" cid:Bitmap1.bmp@embed \"/><br><font size=\"2\" face=\"Courier New\">" + introText + "</font>" + body + "<font size=\"2\" face=\"Courier New\">" + conclText + "</font>" + " </BODY></HTML>";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attc = oMsg.Attachments.Add(imageSrc, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "");
            attc.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", "Bitmap1.bmp@EMBED");

//Send the message.
oMsg.Save();
```

For some reason the email is just showing an x when i try to run this code...anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are not setting the content id properly. Try to change the code to the following:

```
attc.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/bmp"); 
attc.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "Bitmap1.bmp@EMBED");
```

I have done this before a little differently. I embedded images in some emails that I had to send from my web app using an 'alternate view' in the `system.net.mail`

```
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource theContent = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource({path to image});
theContent.ContentID = "TheContent";

String altViewString = anEmail.Body.replace("{original imageSource i.e. '../Images/someimage.gif'}","cid:TheContent");

System.Net.Mail.AlternateView altView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(altViewString, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

altView.LinkedResources.add(theContent);

anEmail.Message.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
```

Comment: out of curiosity which part did you use? the setProperty modifications or the mail library?

Comment: How can I download inline images (embedded images) using C# or powershell from a message ?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea how to even start trying to download or extract embedded images from an email. Depending on how they were embedded it will probably be a case of pulling the source string and then converting it to an image and saving it.

Answer (score 6):

The following is working code with two ways of achieving this:

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Method1();
            Method2();
        }

        public static void Method1()
        {
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
            mailItem.To = "john@example.com";
            string imageSrc = "D:\\Temp\\test.jpg"; // Change path as needed

            var attachments = mailItem.Attachments;
            var attachment = attachments.Add(imageSrc);
            attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/jpeg");
            attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "myident"); // Image identifier found in the HTML code right after cid. Can be anything.
            mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B", true);

            // Set body format to HTML

            mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            string msgHTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>Hello,<br><br>This is a working example of embedding an image unsing C#:<br><br><img align=\"baseline\" border=\"1\" hspace=\"0\" src=\"cid:myident\" width=\"\" 600=\"\" hold=\" /> \"></img><br><br>Regards,<br>Tarik Hoshan</body></html>";
            mailItem.HTMLBody = msgHTMLBody;
            mailItem.Send();
        }

        public static void Method2()
        {

            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            //Add an attachment.
            String attachmentDisplayName = "MyAttachment";

            // Attach the file to be embedded
            string imageSrc = "D:\\Temp\\test.jpg"; // Change path as needed

            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = mailItem.Attachments.Add(imageSrc, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, null, attachmentDisplayName);

            mailItem.Subject = "Sending an embedded image";

            string imageContentid = "someimage.jpg"; // Content ID can be anything. It is referenced in the HTML body

            oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageContentid);

            mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format(
                "<body>Hello,<br><br>This is an example of an embedded image:<br><br><img src=\"cid:{0}\"><br><br>Regards,<br>Tarik</body>",
                imageContentid);

            // Add recipient
            Outlook.Recipient recipient = mailItem.Recipients.Add("john@example.com");
            recipient.Resolve();

            // Send.
            mailItem.Send();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
    private static void insertPictureAsLink(Outlook.MailItem mail, String imagePath, String URI)
    {
        mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        mail.HTMLBody += String.Format("<body><a href={1}><img src=\"{0}\"></body></a>", imagePath, URI);
        mail.Display(false);
    }
```

Comment: This solution links an image, it does not embed it in the mail. Works only for images available on a webserver