# Paste Image in Email Body

Tags: c#, image, outlook, clipboard, com-automation

I need to get my Image (which I have stored in the clipbord before) paste into the E-Mail Body. How can i do it?

Ive tryed `SendKeys.Send("^v");` after the New-Mail Window opend but it didnt work.

Is there maybe a way to put the image directly into the `oMailItem.Body = "";` ?

```
private void mailsenden() // Versendet die E-Mail
    {

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PanelErstmeldung.Width, PanelErstmeldung.Height);
        PanelErstmeldung.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp);
        

        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        _MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        oMailItem.Subject = "Betriebsstörung im Bereich  "+ comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        oMailItem.To = "test@test.com";
        oMailItem.CC = "test2@test2.com";

        oMailItem.Body = "";   // PASTE THE BITMAP bmp HERE in the Body

        oMailItem.Display(true); // Or CTRL+V it here in the opend Window
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding picture to outlook email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938126/embedding-picture-to-outlook-email-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code embeds an image into the message body:

```
Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(
     @"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
    , null, "Some image display name");

   string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";

   attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
    , imageCid
    );

   newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>", imageCid);
```

If you still got an exception in the code I'd suggest using VBA to check whether the code is working correctly.

Comment: @David This is basically the same as my answer, but with the addition of `, OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name"` in the call to `Add()`. Maybe that did it?

Comment: Sometimes tiny details make difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste an image into an email, Outlook attaches the image as a file attachment, then embeds the image into the body. You can do the same in your code. However, [the code to attach a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add?view=outlook-pia#microsoft-office-interop-outlook-attachments-add(system-object-system-object-system-object-system-object)) only works with files on the file system, so you need to save your image to the file system before you attach it, then you can delete it. You don't need to use the clipboard at all.

It would look something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PanelErstmeldung.Width, PanelErstmeldung.Height);
PanelErstmeldung.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

// Save image to temp file
var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
bmp.Save(tempFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMailItem.Subject = "Betriebsstörung im Bereich  "+ comboBox1.SelectedItem;
oMailItem.To = "test@test.com";
oMailItem.CC = "test2@test2.com";

var attachment = oMailItem.Attachments.Add(tempFileName);

// Set the Content ID (CID) of the attachment, which we'll use
// in the body of the email
var imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
             "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);

// Set HTML body with an <img> using the CID we gave it
oMailItem.HTMLBody = $"<body><img src=\"cid:{imageCid}\"></body>";

oMailItem.Display(true);

File.Delete(tempFileName);
```

I'm assuming you have a `using` directive at the top of your file like this:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Comment: Yes I do have the using included.
But Iam getting an Error (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)

here: `attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);`

Comment: @David I just noted the `using` for anyone else coming along who reads my answer.

Comment: @David Does the exception give you any more information? I didn't get that.

Comment: it gives this Error: `HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)` When I try to execute this function in my application.

Comment: @David Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: @David Also, which version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: I'am using `Outlook Version 16.0.13801.21092 32-Bit`

Comment: @David That's a slightly higher version than what I have. Mine is 32-bit too, and it's working just fine for me. That's odd.

Comment: Mine is 32 Bit.